# for loop not iterating through the entire response data in ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 9 columns in my table `choosen_emails_1`, `choosen_emails_2`, `choosen_emails_3`, `booking_address`, `booking_number`, `booking_message`, `booking_date`, `request_date` & `user_email`

The `for` loop iterates and prints everything except `user_email` and `booking_number`

I have used `Println` statement in my controller class to check if the query selector is selecting all columns in my table and it prints all 9 columns

so there is no problem with the back end code. could any one tell me if there is any thing wrong in this jquery! code

```js
data = "";

myfunction = function() {
  $('.tablecontainer').show();
  load();
}

load = function() {

  $.ajax({
      url: 'updatedservicerequests',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {}, // function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
      success: function(response) { // if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
        alert(response.message);
        data = response.data;
        alert(response.data);
        $('.tr').remove();
        alert(response.data);
        $(function() {
            for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

              $("#table").append(response.data[i].user_email + "'>" + response.data[i].booking_number + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_address + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_message + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].request_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_1 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_2 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_3 + "</br>");


            }

            //to prevent (contact-submit) button from submitting form data since submit button has default action of submitting form

            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#contact-submit').click(function(e) {

                return false;
              });
            });
          }
        });

    },
    error: function(response) {
      alert("unable to pull up any service request");
    }
  });
```

```html
<button onclick="myfunction();">Go</button>

<div class="tablecontainer" style="display: none;">

  <table id="table" border=1>
    <tr>
      <th> booking_address </th>
      <th> booking_date </th>
      <th> booking_message </th>
      <th>request date and time </th>
      <th> requested_tech_1 </th>
      <th> requested_tech_2 </th>
      <th>requested_tech_3 </th>
      <th>xyz</th>
      <th>abc</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is missing the `<td>` tags around those two fields, and also the `<tr>` tag around the whole row.

```
$("#table").append(response.data[i].user_email + "'>" + response.data[i].booking_number + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_address + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_message + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].request_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_1 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_2 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_3 + "</br>");
```

You also shouldn't have `</br>` in there -- that's not even a valid tag, and it certainly doesn't belong in a `<table>`.

The correct code is:

```
$("#table").append("<tr> <td> " + response.data[i].user_email + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_number + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_address + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_message + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].request_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_1 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_2 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_3 + "</td> </tr>");
```